# Cannot remove column that doesn't have a data type - SQLite, -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have these three columns in my `Blog` table that do not have data types, e.g: 
`Blog(id: integer, url: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, webname: , name: text, homeurl: , blogname: , home_url: text, blog_name: string)`

Where `homeurl:`, `blogname:`, and `webname:` do not have any datatypes for some reason. Not sure how they were added to the database, but I want to remove them, since my `Blogs` table won't display in the `schema.rb` section of my rails app.

Problem is, all methods I have tried do not work. I have tried to `rake db:migration RemoveColumn` with this as my migration file:

```
class RemoveColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_column :blogs, :homeurl
  end
end
```

This returns the following error: 
`undefined method "to_sym" for nil:NilClass/db/migrate/20150727201931_remove_columns.rb:3:in "up"
NoMethodError: undefined method "to_sym" for nil:NilClass`

I try to add a datatype to the column, I get the same "to_sym" error. I have also tried to delete the column in the console, same error.

Is there a way to delete a column that doesn't have a datatype? Or is there a way to add a datatype to a column where one doesn't exist?

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: near "DROP": syntax error` (from comment, below) does not seem like you're actually using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it into the SQL like this:

```
class RemoveColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "ALTER TABLE blogs DROP homeurl";
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried your answer, but am now getting 'SQLite3::SQLException: near "DROP": syntax error: ALTER TABLE blogs DROP Homeurl/db/migrate/20150727220626_remove_column.rb:3:in `up'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "DROP": syntax error: ALTER TABLE blogs DROP Homeurl
/db/migrate/20150727220626_remove_column.rb:3:in `up'
SQLite3::SQLException: near "DROP": syntax error
/db/migrate/20150727220626_remove_column.rb:3:in `up' as an error.